# Pass URL parameter to ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to pass query parameters to my URL

```
<a ui-sref="customers({foo:'bar'})">Link</a>
```

foo is not a state parameter and should resolve to a regular query parameter

```
<a href="#/customers?foo=bar">Link</a>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You must have state called 'foo'

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this:

```
<a ui-sref="customers({foo:'bar'})">Link</a>
```

you would need something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("customers", {url: "customers?foo", ...});
```

Comment: What do you mean 'arbitrary'?

Comment: the url can accept a number of parameters used to filter the customers.. e.g: name, gender, age, etc..

Comment: And why can't you add those to the state?